# How to solve the simulation issue with Modelica

Tags: compiler-errors, modelica, openmodelica

```
model energygathering
  import Modelica.Units.SI;
  parameter SI.Resistance R=20 "Resistance"; 
  parameter SI.Capacitance C = 2 "Capacitance";
  parameter SI.Current I = 5 "Current";
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Semiconductors.Diode diode annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {12, -18}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Semiconductors.Diode diode1 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {32, 30}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Semiconductors.Diode diode2 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-8, 28}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Semiconductors.Diode diode3 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {6, 56}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Resistor resistor(R = R)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {74, 10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Capacitor capacitor(C = C, v(fixed = true))  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {48, 10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.ConstantCurrent constantCurrent(I = I)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-62, 12}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {68, -54}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(diode1.p, diode.n) annotation(
    Line(points = {{22, 30}, {22, -18}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(diode2.n, diode.p) annotation(
    Line(points = {{2, 28}, {2, -18}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(diode3.n, diode1.n) annotation(
    Line(points = {{16, 56}, {42, 56}, {42, 30}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(capacitor.n, resistor.n) annotation(
    Line(points = {{48, 20}, {74, 20}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(resistor.p, capacitor.p) annotation(
    Line(points = {{74, 0}, {48, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(capacitor.n, diode1.n) annotation(
    Line(points = {{48, 20}, {41, 20}, {41, 30}, {42, 30}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(capacitor.p, diode.p) annotation(
    Line(points = {{48, 0}, {22, 0}, {22, -18}, {2, -18}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(diode2.p, diode3.p) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-18, 28}, {-18, 56}, {-4, 56}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(constantCurrent.n, diode3.p) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-62, 22}, {-64, 22}, {-64, 86}, {-4, 86}, {-4, 56}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(constantCurrent.p, diode.p) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-62, 2}, {-62, -18}, {2, -18}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(capacitor.p, ground.p) annotation(
    Line(points = {{48, 0}, {48, -21}, {68, -21}, {68, -44}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "4.0.0")));
end energygathering;
```

But when I try to simulate this I have this message :

/usr/bin/sh: clang -I. -o energygathering.exe energygathering.o energygathering_functions.o energygathering_records.o energygathering_01exo.o energygathering_02nls.o energygathering_03lsy.o energygathering_04set.o energygathering_05evt.o energygathering_06inz.o energygathering_07dly.o energygathering_08bnd.o energygathering_09alg.o energygathering_10asr.o energygathering_11mix.o energygathering_12jac.o energygathering_13opt.o energygathering_14lnz.o energygathering_15syn.o energygathering_16dae.o energygathering_17inl.o energygathering_18spd.o -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.20.0-64bit/include/omc/c" -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.20.0-64bit/include/omc" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=energygathering -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=4 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0 -L"C:/Users/venet/OneDrive/Ξ¥Ο€ΞΏΞ»ΞΏΞ³ΞΉΟƒΟ„Ξ®Ο‚"    -Os -Wno-parentheses-equality -falign-functions -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.20.0-64bit/include/omc/c" -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.20.0-64bit/include/omc" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=energygathering -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=4 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0 -L"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.20.0-64bit/lib//omc" -L"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.20.0-64bit/lib" -Wl,--stack,16777216,-rpath,"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.20.0-64bit/lib//omc" -L"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.20.0-64bit/bin" -Wl,-rpath,"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.20.0-64bit/lib"  -fopenmp -Wl,-Bstatic -lregex -ltre -lintl -liconv -lexpat -lpthread -loleaut32 -limagehlp -lhdf5 -lz -lszip -Wl,-Bdynamic -lSimulationRuntimeC -Wl,-Bdynamic -lomcgc -lopenblas -Wl,-Bdynamic  -lstdc++ -Wl,-Bdynamic  : No such file or directory
mingw32-make: *** [energygathering.makefile:37: omc_main_target] Error 127
mingw32-make: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/venet/AppData/Local/Temp/OPENMO~1/OMEdit/ENERGY~1'
Compilation process failed. Exited with code 0x00000002.

I tried to just move the file from the AppData folder to desktop but it didnt work.

Comment: The problem is the working directory, it contains special characters.  Change it to something like c:\temp and it should work.

Comment: The model itself works after adding a semicolon at the end (I have edited the code in the original post).